# Getting 404 error on asp .net core application after changing https port

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, server

In IIS manager , I changed port of https from 443 to 9000, but after changing it it is giving me 404 error.

Comment: If you changed the port, you should use the new port to access the application, like xxxx:9000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do troubleshooting step is to find out whether the problem is with your .NET Core application or with your IIS Hosting configuration.

Try below steps from the root of your project:

1. `dotnet restore`
2. `dotnet run`